# Mount NTFS on Ubuntu on start up

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ntfs

I would like to know what do I have to do if I want to mount automatically my NTFS filesystem when Ubuntu 10 starts. Now I have to do it manually everytime it starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fo this by editing the FSTAB:

First create a directory where your NTFS volume will be mounted to:

```
sudo mkdir /media/ntfs
```

Wise man makes a backup before editing the FSTAB:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab-backup
```

Append this at the end of the file

```
/dev/hda1    /media/windows ntfs  nls=utf8,umask=0222 0    0
```

Instead of /dev/hda1 use your dev here.

Comment: I'm using `uid=1000,gid=1000,auto,rw,users` instead of `nls=utf8,umask=0222` to auto mount the ntfs partition at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Change you fstab should help.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab.

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome Example section in the Ubuntu Wiki for Fstab:

```
# NTFS ~ Use ntfs-3g for write access (rw) 
# /dev/hda1
UUID=12102C02102CEB83  /media/windows  ntfs-3g  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137,utf8  0  0
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Examples

Answer (score 0):

**Tip1**: To find errors during mounting, read the terminal output of 'umount ntfs / mount ntfs'.
See also https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access

**Tip2**: A dual boot Windows 8, 10, 11 may leave the NTFS partition in an unclean state when it shuts down.
See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Then you should search and execute 'disable fast startup option' for your Windows version.

**Tip3**: In Ubuntu 23.4 (probably earlier and later also), there is the graphical app 'Disks'. You can edit 'fstab' from the UI as below

- use mount options = 'defaults'
- use your mount point like '/mnt/ntfs' or '/mnt/NTFS'
- use the automatically provided partition ID or name

[image: Linux Disks mount options for NTFS partition]