# How do I specify a label/path with spaces in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, hard-drive

I am having trouble trying to get theh permissions for some of my external drives set up.

I believe the probem is due to how I am dealing with spaces in the text such that the commands can be interpreted by the terminal.
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224243/mount-ntfs-on-ubuntu-on-start-up), which seems to indicate that I need to configure my etc/fstab file to show the following:

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
LABEL='Expansion Drive'  /media/'Expansion Drive'  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
LABEL='Expansion Drive_'  /media/'Expansion Drive_'  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
```

However, This is showing an error that the drive `Drive_'` is not ready.  I realize that this is due to using `""`s or `''`s, but I am not sure how else to do this properly.  My 2 drives are called `Expansion Drive` and `Expansion Drive_` .  Anyone know how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** Here is what I can see in the media folder:

```
chasebrown@ubuntu:/media$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  6 root       root        1024 Mar  9 16:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root       root        1024 Feb 23 23:14 ..
drwx------  1 chasebrown chasebrown  4096 Mar  8 04:21 Expansion Drive
drwx------  1 chasebrown chasebrown  4096 Mar  8 04:21 Expansion Drive_
dr-x------  1 chasebrown chasebrown  2048 May 20  2009 GDRV-25922+VR2
drwx------  1 chasebrown chasebrown 20480 Mar  8 04:21 WD EXTERNAL
```

Also `sudo lsblk -f`:

```
chasebrown@ubuntu:/dev/disk/by-uuid$ sudo lsblk -f
[sudo] password for chasebrown: 
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL           MOUNTPOINT
sda                            
├─sda1 ntfs    System Reserved 
└─sda2 ntfs                    
sdb                            
└─sdb1 ntfs                    /host
sdc                            
└─sdc1 ntfs    Expansion Drive /media/Expansion Drive_
sdd                            
└─sdd1 ntfs    Expansion Drive /media/Expansion Drive
sde                            
└─sde1 ntfs    WD EXTERNAL     /media/WD EXTERNAL
sr0    iso9660 GDRV-25922+VR2  /media/GDRV-25922+VR2
loop0  ext3                    /
```

And `sudo blkid`:

```
chasebrown@ubuntu:/dev/disk/by-uuid$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: UUID="87a15942-982f-4edd-bf44-439dc286fd7c" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="GDRV-25922+VR2" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="64CEEA61CEEA2B4E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="4CA4EBC0A4EBAAA2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="00064EEE064EE46E" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Expansion Drive" UUID="C682A8EE82A8E3E1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Expansion Drive" UUID="D006D78406D769CC" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sde1: LABEL="WD EXTERNAL" UUID="D65AFC375AFC15C9" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Therefore my new fstab file is:

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
LABEL=Expansion\040Drive  /media/Expansion\040Drive  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
LABEL=Expansion\040Drive_  /media/Expansion\040Drive_  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
```

**SOLUTION**: 
I ended up changing the `LABEL` to `UUID` and it worked for some reason.

Here is the resulting /etc/fstab file was :

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=C682A8EE82A8E3E1  /media/Expansion\040Drive  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
UUID=D006D78406D769CC  /media/Expansion\040Drive_  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
```

Comment: Why was this flagged as off-topic? Because it's supposed to be on _ServerFault_ or _Unix & Linux_ or something similar? It would have been nice if the person closing this question also added a short explanation _why_ it's off-topic.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can use the escape sequence `\040` to escape spaces:

```
# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk    none    swap    sw  0   0
LABEL=Expansion\040Drive  /media/Expansion\040Drive  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
LABEL=Expansion\040Drive_  /media/Expansion\040Drive_  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
```

BTW, you cannot quote part of the string like you mentioned in the question. If you're quoting, you need to quote the entire string.

Another thing I happen to notice from the output of `blkid` is that there are 2 partitions (on 2 separate drives `sdc1` and `sdd1`) both having the same LABEL `Expansion Drive`. To workaround this, you can use UUID instead.

```
UUID=C682A8EE82A8E3E1  /media/Expansion\040Drive  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
UUID=D006D78406D769CC  /media/Expansion\040Drive_  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,fmask=0133  0  0
```

Comment: The same error message came up, but it referenced `/media/Expansion Drive` , which appears to be correct.
I have included a view of what I can see of the drivers in my question now if that helps.

Comment: @chase, I just tried the same approach I mentioned in the answer of using `LABEL=Expansion\040Drive` and the mount point `/media/Expansion\040Drive` and it seems to work for me. Could you check once again if you have both these changes ?

Comment: @chase - It seems you have the same `LABEL` for both `sdc1` and `sdd1`. It is better to use UUID for these situations instead.